# Vectorisation of a for loop

Tags: vectorization

I have a nested for loop and I have already managed to vectorise one dimension, but since the other dimension is also large, I was looking for a way to vectorise this dimension too. Please help.

```py
def g(x,y):
    return np.exp((np.linalg.norm(x-y, axis=1)**2))

y[i] = np.sum(a*s*g(np.tile(X[i],(n,1)),s_x).reshape((n,1)))
```

now a is of dim(n,1), s of dim(n,1), X[i] of dim(1,p), s_x of dim(n,p)

any ideas on this? I have tried a long time but I am not able to get to any conclusion, please help.

Comment: Please help someone! hints would also work!!!!!

Comment: Please help!!!!